# Subtraction in SQL statement for stock

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

A database lists items and their stock count. When someone buys items I wish to update the stock count in the database.

Regardless of the following subtraction `f_item_number = f_item_number - $mugAmount`, my update statement isn't working.

If I have 200 mugs in the database. When I run the following statement the new mug amount is listed incorrectly afterwards as -1. Rather than the expected value of 199. Why is this?

```
DB::update('UPDATE `shop_items` SET `f_item_number` = ? WHERE `f_item_name` = ?', array(`f_item_number` - $mugAmount, "mug"));
```

Comment: When someone provides an answer which is the solution, you can 'checkmark' the answer (under the rating of an answer). The question will then be marked as solved :). I also see you have other questions open where you didn't 'accept' the best answer yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass in database column text in the parameters. Try this

```
DB::update('UPDATE `shop_items` SET `f_item_number` = `f_item_number` - ? WHERE `f_item_name` = ?', array($mugAmount, "mug"));
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you a lot